# Src Switch using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want, when you click one video or image from the list it will change the main image/video. I did this already but the thing is that when i added the video part it wouldn't work any more, here the code.

```
  <div id="Post-Image">
    <img id="Post-Image-Pic" src="<?php echo $row["Post_1"];?>" width="408" alt="#"/>
  </div> 
  <video controls id="Post-Video">
    <source  id="Post-Video-Source" src="<?php echo $row["Post_1"];?>" >
  </video>

<div id="List"> // this is the list
  <?php 
    $Video_Allow  = array('avi', 'mov', 'qt', 'mkv', 'mp4', 'avchd', 'flv', 'swf');
    $Image_Allow = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf', 'gif');
    if ($row["Post_1"] != "") {
      ?>
        <style> #Post-List{ display: none; }</style>
        <?php
          $File_Ext_1 = explode('.', $row["Post_1"]);
          $File_Actual_Ext_1 = strtolower(end($File_Ext_1));
          if (in_array($File_Actual_Ext_1, $Image_Allow)) {
           ?>
              <img src="<?php echo $row["Post_1"];?>" onclick="MyImage1();
                document.getElementById('Post-Image-Pic').src='<?php echo $row["Post_1"];?>';
                document.getElementById('Post-Video').style.display= 'none';
                document.getElementById('Post-Image').style.display= 'block';
              "/>
            <?php
          }elseif (in_array($File_Actual_Ext_1, $Video_Allow)) {
            ?>
              <video src="<?php echo $row["Post_1"];?>" onclick="MyImage1(); 
                document.getElementById('Post-Video-Source').src='<?php echo $row["Post_1"];?>'; 
                document.getElementById('Post-Video').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('Post-Image').style.display = 'none';
              "/>
            <?php
          }
        ?>
      <?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

if you want to know what is the Image1(); is here

```
        var stm1 = document.getElementById("Comment1"),
            stm2 = document.getElementById("Comment2"),
            stm3 = document.getElementById("Comment3"),
            stm4 = document.getElementById("Comment4"),
            stm5 = document.getElementById("Comment5"),
            stm6 = document.getElementById("Comment6");
        stm1.style.display = "block";
        stm2.style.display = "none";
        stm3.style.display = "none";
        stm4.style.display = "none";
        stm5.style.display = "none";
        stm6.style.display = "none";
        function MyImage1() {
            stm1.style.display = "block";
            stm2.style.display = "None";
            stm3.style.display = "None";
            stm4.style.display = "None";
            stm5.style.display = "None";
            stm6.style.display = "None";
        }
        function MyImage2() {
            stm1.style.display = "none";
            stm2.style.display = "block";
            stm3.style.display = "none";
            stm4.style.display = "none";
            stm5.style.display = "none";
            stm6.style.display = "none";
        }
```

look this is when you click a image/video it will change the comment for each post you make, so that mean 1 image/video hast a commenting part.

Comment: So before `MyImage1` worked fine, but then you added a bunch of extra code to the `onclick` and now nothing is working?

Comment: Neither image nor video has an `id` ...?  Where/what is `MyImage1()`?

Comment: I need you to just fix the ` document.getElementById('Post-Image-Pic').src='<?php echo $row["Post_1"];?>'; `

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the elements/ids at the top. Hard to say what is going on without seeing `MyImage1()`. Neither `<img>` nor `<source>` have a `value`, so setting `.val()` on them won't work. What actually happens?  Any errors on the console?

Comment: if you want to see the other page I'm editing it